# how to convert a json data according to requirement?

Tags: php, json

I have a json data and needs to convert according to my requirement using php. Please help me to convert json data to according to my requirement. I want to
serialize array using key number and food_type. If the number is same then put into the same array, also if food_type same then also put their content on food_content array.

Here is the my code:

```
 [{
"number": "1",
"food_type": "early_morning_breakfast",
"food_id": "839",
"name": "Rotisserie Chicken",
"food_serving": "1",
"calories": "322",
"food_serving_unit": "Piece",
"recipe_id": "1",
"recipe_type": "Veg"
}, {
"number": "1",
"food_type": "early_morning_breakfast",
"food_id": "18",
"name": "Prawn Biryani",
"food_serving": "1",
"calories": "125",
"food_serving_unit": "Bowl",
"recipe_id": "3",
"recipe_type": "Non-Veg"
 }, {
"number": "2",
"food_type": "breakfast",
"food_id": "6",
"name": "Aloo Shimla Mirch",
"food_serving": "1",
"calories": "225",
"food_serving_unit": "Bowl",
"recipe_id": "",
"recipe_type": ""
}, {
"number": "3",
"food_type": "evening_snacks",
"food_id": "5",
"name": "Aloo Methi",
"food_serving": "1",
"calories": "167",
"food_serving_unit": "Bowl",
"recipe_id": "",
"recipe_type": ""
 }]
```

I need to convert like this:

```
[{
"name": "1",
"data": [{
    "food_type": "early_morning_breakfast",
    "food_content": [{
        "food_id": "839",
        "name": "Rotisserie Chicken",
        "food_serving": "1",
        "calories": "322",
        "food_serving_unit": "Piece",
        "recipe_id": "1",
        "recipe_type": "Veg"
    }, {
        "food_id": "18",
        "name": "Prawn Biryani",
        "food_serving": "1",
        "calories": "125",
        "food_serving_unit": "Bowl",
        "recipe_id": "3",
        "recipe_type": "Non-Veg"
    }]
    }]
 }, {
"name": "2",
"data": [{
    "food_type": "breakfast",
    "food_content": [{
        "food_id": "6",
        "name": "Aloo Shimla Mirch",
        "food_serving": "1",
        "calories": "225",
        "food_serving_unit": "Bowl",
        "recipe_id": "",
        "recipe_type": ""
    }]
   }]
  }, {
"name": "3",
"data": [{
    "food_type": "evening_snacks",
    "food_content": [{
        "food_id": "5",
        "name": "Aloo Methi",
        "food_serving": "1",
        "calories": "167",
        "food_serving_unit": "Bowl",
        "recipe_id": "",
        "recipe_type": ""
    }]
    }]
    }]
```

Comment: `json_decode()` a loop and constructing a new array would help. But have you tried anything?

Comment: yes tried but not getting the same output, can you help?

Comment: Show us what have you tried

Comment: What did you do to achieve this? Show your code/efforts here.StackOverflow is not a code writing service. If you have a problem with your code, please provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.